# building img tag jquery php string via echo not working

Tags: php, jquery, echo, image

Hey all i am trying to get this working here:

```
<? 
echo ('<script type="text/javascript">
$(\'#fileupload\').fileupload({
}).bind(\'fileuploaddone\', function (e, data) {
    jQuery("#shadow").attr("src", "bannerImg/slider/\'' . 
    ' + jQuery(\"#slideNum\").val(); + ');
    echo ('\'.jpg");
    jQuery("#theText").html("New Slider Image:");') ?>
```

After it uploads an image it calls this script and i need it to see what value is selected in the select box. However, all i am getting this:

So naturally it does not work with showing the image. How can i rework this in order to get it working the way i need it too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('#fileupload').fileupload({
    }).bind('fileuploaddone', function (e, data) {
    jQuery("#shadow").attr("src", "bannerImg/slider/" + jQuery("#slideNum").val() + '.jpg');
    jQuery("#theText").html("New Slider Image:");
```

instead of:

```
<? 
echo ('<script type="text/javascript">
$(\'#fileupload\').fileupload({
}).bind(\'fileuploaddone\', function (e, data) {
    jQuery("#shadow").attr("src", "bannerImg/slider/\'' . 
    ' + jQuery(\"#slideNum\").val(); + ');
    echo ('\'.jpg");
    jQuery("#theText").html("New Slider Image:");') ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php if($_POST['submit']){ ?>

       <script>
       //your script here
       </script>

<?php } ?>
```

follow this idea, instead of echoing your script better to put your script inside a 2 PHP enclosed tags like the above code..

Comment: Alright i did that and i got it working. Thanks Clint for the hint.

Comment: your welcome.. also echoing some html and other script than PHP would be more easy if are doing something like this especially tags with quotes "" or ''.. :)